# How to mark one function not a test for pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tensorflow, pytest

I'm using pytest to test some code based on TensorFlow.

A `TestCase` is defined for simplicity like:

```
class TestCase(tf.test.TestCase):
    # ...
```

The problem is `tf.test.TestCase` provide a useful function `self.test_session()`, which was treated as a test method in pytest since its name starts with `test_`.

The result pytest report more succeed tests than test methods I defined due to `test_session()` methods.

I use the following code to skip `test_session`:

```
class TestCase(tf.test.TestCase):
    @pytest.mark.skip
    @contextmanager
    def test_session(self):
        with super().test_session() as sess:
            yield sess
```

However there would be some "s" in test report indicating there are some skip tests.

Is there anyway I can mark one exact method not a test method without changing pytest test discovery rules globally?

Comment: What does the `tf.test.TestCase` class give you that you want to re-use?  The best course of action would be to see if you can get that setup and teardown into a pytest fixture instead.

Comment: Call your function `make_session` or something that doesn't start `test_`. https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-discovery

Comment: @Hitobat  You're missing the point - `test_session` is inherited from the parent hence the name can't be changed.

Comment: Oh, I thought this was your code and you could change the name.

Comment: From Tensorflow's documentation `test_session()` seems to be deprecated in favour of `cached_session()`. In the code itself, no other method seems to call `test_session()`. It might be safe to use `del tf.test.TestCase.test_session` after it has been imported, wrapped in a try/catch if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter out false positives after the test items are collected: create a `conftest.py` in your tests directory with the custom post-collection hook:

```
# conftest.py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    items[:] = [item for item in items if item.name != 'test_session']
```

`pytest` will still collect the `test_session` methods (you will notice that in the `pytest` report line `collected n tests`), but not execute them as tests and not consider them anywhere in the test run.

---

#### Related: fix for `unittest`-style tests

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55440264/2650249).

Comment: Amazing! This solution solved the problem perfectly. This configuration file still works even if I am using pytest in a sub directory.

Answer (score 4):

You can set `__test__ = False`, either directly, or by writing a simple decorator. The latter should behave similarly to Nose's `nottest` decorator.

```py
def nottest(obj):
    obj.__test__ = False
    return obj

class TestMyTest:

    def test_should_not_collect_1(self):
        assert False
    test_should_not_collect_1.__test__ = False

    @nottest
    def test_should_not_collect_2(self):
        assert False

    def test_should_collect(self):
        assert True


def test_should_not_collect_1():
    assert False
test_should_not_collect_1.__test__ = False

@nottest
def test_should_not_collect_2():
    assert False


def test_should_collect():
    assert True
```

When running pytest, this only runs the methods which are not marked:

```
$ pytest test.py -v
====================================== test session starts ======================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /Users/lucaswiman/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/bin/python3.9
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /private/tmp
plugins: anyio-2.2.0
collected 2 items                                                                               

test.py::TestMyTest::test_should_collect PASSED                                           [ 50%]
test.py::test_should_collect PASSED                                                       [100%]

======================================= 2 passed in 0.04s =======================================
```

This behavior is documented [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/pythoncollection.html):

> Since Pytest 2.6, users can prevent pytest from discovering classes that start with Test by setting a boolean `__test__` attribute to `False`.

Answer (score -2):

There is way to do it in unittest

```
@unittest.skip("skipping reason")
```

tf.test has skipTest(reason) read more at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/TestCase#skipTest

Comment: The OP has already skipped the tests, but is not happy with the result.