# Phantom tests after switching from unittest.TestCase to tf.test.TestCase

Tags: python, unit-testing, tensorflow, python-unittest

The following code:

```
class BoxListOpsTest(unittest.TestCase):                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    """Tests for common bounding box operations."""                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

    def test_area(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        corners = tf.constant([[0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]])                                                                                                                                                                                         
        exp_output = [200.0, 4.0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        boxes = box_list.BoxList(corners)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        areas = box_list_ops.area(boxes)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

        with tf.Session() as sess:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            areas_output = sess.run(areas)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            np.testing.assert_allclose(areas_output, exp_output)                                                                                                                                                                                                      


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    unittest.main()
```

Is interpreted as a test case with a single test:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.471s

OK
```

However, switching to `tf.test.TestCase`:

```
class BoxListOpsTest(tf.test.TestCase):                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    """Tests for common bounding box operations."""                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

    def test_area(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        corners = tf.constant([[0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]])                                                                                                                                                                                         
        exp_output = [200.0, 4.0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        boxes = box_list.BoxList(corners)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        areas = box_list_ops.area(boxes)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        # with self.session() as sess:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        with tf.Session() as sess:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            areas_output = sess.run(areas)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            np.testing.assert_allclose(areas_output, exp_output)                                                                                                                                                                                                      


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    tf.test.main()
```

introduces some second test, which is skipped:

```
.s
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.524s

OK (skipped=1)
```

What is the origin of the second test and should I worry about it?

I am using TensorFlow 1.13.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the [`tf.test.TestCase.test_session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/TestCase#test_session) method. Due to the unlucky naming, `unittest` considers `test_session` method to be a test and adds it to the test suite. To prevent running `test_session` as a test, Tensorflow has to skip it internally, so it results in a "skipped" test:

```
def test_session(self,
                 graph=None,
                 config=None,
                 use_gpu=False,
                 force_gpu=False):
    if self.id().endswith(".test_session"):
        self.skipTest("Not a test.")
```

Verify the skipped test is the `test_session` by running your test with a `--verbose` flag. You should see an output similar to this:

```
...
test_session (BoxListOpsTest)
Use cached_session instead. (deprecated) ... skipped 'Not a test.'
```

Although the `test_session` is deprecated since 1.11 and should be replaced with `cached_session` ([related commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/9962eb5e84b15e309410071b06c2ed2d6148ed44)), as of now, it's not scheduled for removal in 2.0 yet. In order to get rid of it, you can apply custom filter on collected tests.

#### `unittest`

You can define a custom [`load_tests`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol) function:

```
test_cases = (BoxListOpsTest, )

def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    for test_class in test_cases:
        tests = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(test_class)
        filtered_tests = [t for t in tests if not t.id().endswith('.test_session')]
        suite.addTests(filtered_tests)
    return suite
```

#### `pytest`

Add a custom [`pytest_collection_modifyitems`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) hook in your `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    items[:] = [item for item in items if item.name != 'test_session']
```