# test_session deprecation warning when instantiating tf.test.TestCase

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, testing

I know that [`test_session` is deprecated in `tensorflow 1.13`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/TestCase#test_session):

> Warning: THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future
>   version. Instructions for updating: Use self.session() or
>   self.cached_session() instead.

I created a unit test by only inheriting from `tf.test.TestCase` (which as I understand it is not deprecated?). I was careful not to explicitly call `test_session`:

```
class TestModelFn(tf.test.TestCase):

    def test_nothing(self):
        pass
```

However, when I run this test I see this:

```
test_nothing (the_thing.test.objective.cost_based.test_model.TestModelFn) ... ok
test_session (the_thing.test.objective.cost_based.test_model.TestModelFn)
Use cached_session instead. (deprecated) ... skipped 'Not a test.'
```

Why is this happening? I'm using `tensorflow 1.13.1`.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55440264/2650249) is a proposal to get rid of the skipped `test_session` in test run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `test_session` is named like a test method, therefore your test runner will attempt to run it triggering the deprecation warning and [`'Not a test'`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/test_util.py#L1938) message.

Comment: Ha! That's great, I never would have thought of that.